# Align anchor ( <a> ) tags to appear in same line using basic CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried creating three anchor tag elements and added some CSS to it. I was expecting all of them to be appearing in the same line but it doesn't work. Below is my code. What i need to do to make them appear in same line? I already tried inline, inline-block and float... didn't work.

```css
.nav1 {
  margin-left: 800px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav2 {
  margin-left: 900px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav3 {
  margin-left: 1000px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <a class="nav1" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="nav2" href="#">Resume</a>
  <a class="nav3" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You are make a mistake #fff to link color so, nothing to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<a>` elements aren't inline as expected is because of the very large margins you're giving them, and that they are inline elements. For example, for `.nav2`, it will be 800px + nav1's width + 900px from the side of the viewport. However, since it is too wide, it will simply break into the next line.

What you want is to use a combination of flexbox and a fixed width for each element, since all your anchor elements should be 100px apart. The width of `.red` is set to `800px + (3 * 100px)` just so the layout works:

```css
.red {
  display: flex;
  width: 1100px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.nav:first-child {
  margin-left: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <a class="nav" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#">Resume</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
Scroll right to view links, as you have given them a large left margin.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` to `.red` container and remove the margins:

```
.red {
   display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Or... just remove the margins. Flex has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

use the property `display:flex` as below

```css
.red{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
 <div class="red">
    <a class="nav1" href="#">Home </a> 
    <a class="nav2" href="#">Resume </a>
    <a class="nav3" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: You get nearly the exact same result if you simply remove all styles. Why does there seem to be an attitude of "Just add flex, it fixes everything" at the moment?? (If you were to actually make use of the positioning it would make sense)

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample snippet. the issue is the margins. and you don't need to use separate classes if you only need links to be inline.

```
    .red a {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #0d0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

is enough I think.you can play with following snippet and check.

```css
.red {
  display: flex;
}

.nav1 {
  /*margin-left: 800px;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #0d0;
}

.nav2 {
  /*margin-left: 900px;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #0d0;
}

.nav3 {
  /*margin-left: 1000px;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #0d0;
}

.red a {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #0d0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
    <a class="nav1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="nav2" href="#">Resume</a>
    <a class="nav3" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Change **color** ( you are given `#fff` ) of every link (**nav1 ,nav2 ,nav3** ).

Then, Add `width` as `max-content` to red div.

```
.red{
  width:max-content;
}
```

more info about max-content: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/#max-content

Also add `inline-block` each link.

```css
.nav1 {
  margin-left: 800px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #111;
  display:inline-block;
}

.nav2 {
  margin-left: 900px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #111;
  display:inline-block;
}

.nav3 {
  margin-left: 1000px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #111;
  display:inline-block;
}
.red{
  width:max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <a class="nav1" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="nav2" href="#">Resume</a>
  <a class="nav3" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
  you are link color #fff that is white nothing to be seen. Go to right ---->
```

This must work.

Comment: @suru92  try this add red div to width as `max-content` and also add every link to `inline-block`.